# How to print last element in set in C++

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set

I am trying to print last element of a set `set<int>s;` where actual last element is 9.

```
set<int>:: iterator it=s.begin();
while(it!=s.end())
{
    cout<<*it<<endl;
    it++;
}
```

when i use this loop ,through this set, it shows that last element is 9 which is correct.

but when is use this piece of code it shows last element is 4 which is incorrect.

```
int setint= *s.end();
cout<<setint<<endl;
```

but when I use this code to print first element of a set ,it prints first element correctly

```
int setint= *s.begin();
    cout<<setint<<endl;
```

how should i fis this?

Comment: `end()` returns a non-dereferencable iterator to an imaginary element one position past the actual last element. Derecrement it to get the iterator to the last element.

Comment: Read the documentation of [`end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/end) method please.

Comment: if you look closely at your first snippet you see that the while loop is not executed for `it == s.end()`, the last iteration is that with the element before `s.end()`

Comment: All intervals in the library are half-open and are speciified by the beginning and one-past-the-end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`end()` points *past-the-end* of a collection. It should never be dereferenced.

You can use [`rbegin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/rbegin) instead:

```
if (!myset.empty()) {
    cout << *myset.rbegin() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

end is actually "pointing" to an element beyond the content of the set:

[image]

and instead you should use the reverse iterator:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/rbegin

```
if (!mySet.empty())
{
    std::cout << "Last element is: " << *mySet.rbegin() << std::endl; 
}
```